# OnsenUi - How to disable page drag effect

Tags: onsen-ui

is page dragging down a feature in onsenui or is it a bug on my code?

Anyway to prevent this?

[Screenshot - white space page dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIQRX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Onsen yet, but I fixed this back in the day using the DisallowOverscroll parameter in Cordova's config.xml.

It seems to still exist in the [latest release](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/) and is available in both Android and iOS.